# Caption styling on jw player

Tags: jwplayer

Can someone tell me how can I style my caption properly on jw player. It is being shown as below which is bit annoying for users.

```
tracks: [{ 
                    file: "subs/<?php echo $a; ?>-en.vtt",
                    label: "English",
                    kind: "captions",
                    "default": true,
                fontSize: 24,
                backgroundOpacity: 50
                }]
```

[image]

Comment: How would you like to style it? Bigger? Another font?

Answer (score 0):

They have a demo on their web site on how you can style captions:

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/customization/captions-styling/

Comment: not able to understand how to implement it. Pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, setting up the captions styling in this way worked for me:

```
jwplayer("video-player").setup({
  file: "https://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/#{jw_identifier}.m3u8",
  image: "#{videoable.poster_url(1920)}",
  captions: {
    color: "#4D4D4F",
    fontFamily: "Arial",
    fontOpacity: 100,
    edgeStyle: "none",
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    windowColor: "#ffffff",
    windowOpacity: 0,
    backgroundOpacity: 100
  }
})
```

Here is a link to JW Player's documentation outlining the captions styling configuration: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/#captions